# Show year when you are browsing your own questions on your profile

Tags: feature-request, bug

If your are browsing for questions on your own profile (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/0000000/someuser?tab=questions&sort=newest) you only see the day, month and time sometimes (despite it is from last year).

E.g.

> aug 25 at 14:11 testing 5,130

Here only the active date (and user) will be shown. Sometimes the year is given, but not in all cases. Don't know if this is a bug.

I find it much more easier to actually see the year if it is the last year.

Comment: I perhaps removed the bug tag prematurely.

Comment: The behavior does seem to be broken, or at least surprising, for questions. I cannot see any obvious reason for why dates are omitted after a certain point in time, while for answers, the year is omitted only if it's the current year.

Comment: Looking at OP's questions, the `'15` starts to [appear somewhat randomly in the middle of August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426227/testing?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=3). Once the year starts to appear, it looks like it will always appear on later posts, so whatever cutoff date is being used to show/hide the year seems to be set to a weird/wrong value.